# Perl Delete multiple lines from csv file beginning with specific string

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have a csv file having data as below format.

```
09:20:02.063,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:20:08.425,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:02.684,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:03.188,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:05.552,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:03.914,113.600,110.300,110.600
09:23:04.282,112.600,110.300,110.600
09:23:05.643,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:01.004,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:05.369,110.600,110.300,110.600
```

What I want to do is to remove the entire rows that beginning as “09:23”,
However the data format consist of Hour:Minute:Second.Millisecond. It is difficult for me to using Perl to just specific “Hour:Minute” to remove the rows. Any advice, Thanks

Expected result

```
09:20:02.063,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:20:08.425,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:02.684,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:03.188,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:05.552,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:03.914,113.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:01.004,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:05.369,110.600,110.300,110.600
```

Comment: Since you're new to Stack Overflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
$ perl -lne 'print if !/^09:23\b/' file
09:20:02.063,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:20:08.425,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:02.684,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:21:03.188,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:05.552,110.600,110.300,110.600
09:22:03.914,113.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:01.004,111.600,110.300,110.600
09:24:05.369,110.600,110.300,110.600
```

Or

With grep,

```
grep -v '^09:23\b' file
```

Comment: or `perl -ne 'print if !/^09:23:/' file`